# JavaScript - Undefined link when I change href of a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, undefined, href

I use code from [HERE (Stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655598/php-how-to-change-iframe-different-src-after-every-5-second)

I do it for my stuff like this

```
var i = 0;
var links = ["http://www.example.com/page","http://www.example.com/anotherpage"];
var renew = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("changelink").href = links[i];        
    if(links.length==i){
        i=0;
    }else{
        i++;
    }
},5000);
<a id='changelink' href='http://google.bg/'>test</a>
```

but when the link change it writes me undefined, I try with the same code with iframe and also gives me undefined whats going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your count is off by one

```
var i = 0;
var links = ["http://www.example.com/page", "http://www.example.com/anotherpage"];
var renew = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("changelink").href = links[i];
    if (links.length - 1 == i) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}, 5000);
```

When `links.length == i` you're actually trying to get an array index that doesn't exists, so you'll have to subtract one and do `links.length - 1 == i`

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov - Then you're doing something else wrong, as this works just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Q7nbq/**